# Generating an external url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to construct a url within my rails app that points to another server that isn't running rails. Using `url_for` almost satisfies my requirements, but it requires a controller key which I don't need (redirecting to a top level page on the external site).

The reason I want to do this is so that I have a cleanly construct a url with a hash of arguments (some of which are determined at runtime).

Comment: Gotta love Google - 1 hour after you ask your question, it's the 6th result for 'rails generate external url'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think about [URI::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/)?

Comment: unfortunately i can't pass in the query string as a has as I would have preferred, but it's close enough. I find it a bit odd that using `HTTPS::build` with the `to_s` method returns a https uri, while using the `request_uri` method returns a http uri.

Comment: I do not know an easy solution for the hash into prameters problem. If you dont't need nested parameters you can probably create a simple function to do this. The URI::HTTPS.request_uri() Function returns only the path and query string. Everything before is left out. You can try it easily in the Rails console.

Comment: Rails provides a [`to_query`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_query) method on `Hash` that can be used with the `query` param on `URI::HTTP.build` that might do what you'd like.

Answer (score 39):

You can call `to_query` on Hash in rails which will take care of url encoding etc.  So maybe something like this:

```
params = {
  :a => "http://google.com",
  :b => 123
}
url = "http://example.com?#{params.to_query}"
```